# Inner joining on a calculated column

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm having some trouble writing a query which performs an inner join.

In my database table I have columns Date, HighTemperature, LowTemperature. What I am wanting is to calculate things like highest temperature by month of the year, retrieving the date these occurred on simultaneously. This works fine, using the query below:

```
SELECT ds.Date, 
    MONTH(ds.Date) AS Month, 
    ds.HighTemperature 
FROM WeatherData.DailyStats ds 
INNER JOIN (SELECT MONTH(Date) AS Month, 
        Date, 
        MAX(HighTemperature) AS HighTemperature 
    FROM WeatherData.DailyStats GROUP BY Month) ds2 
    ON MONTH(ds.Date) = MONTH(ds2.Date) AND ds.HighTemperature = ds2.HighTemperature 
ORDER BY MONTH(ds.Date), ds.DATE ASC
```

This gives me 12 rows, one for each month of the year. Each row contains the month number, the highest temperature recorded in that month and the date it occurred on.

Now where I'm not having any success is when trying to do something slightly more tricky - instead of running the query directly on HighTemperature, I want to find the highest daily temperature ranges for each month, i.e. get the same sort of results for `(HighTemperature - LowTemperature) AS TemperatureRange`.

How can I modify the query to do this?

Comment: One issue you may encounter is when two dates have the same high temperature in the same month, you'll get two output rows for that month. Adding a proper group by may help in that regard. As far as getting the same thing for temperature range, you should be able to get that by simply replacing the HighTemperature with your formula. But again, you'll need to add a group by for proper results. Also, the date column in your sub-select is irrelevant, and because there is not group by, inaccurate.

Comment: @SloanThrasher The date in the subquery is used in the join ON statement. Also I can't just replace with my formula because the `ds.HighTemperature = ds2.HighTemperature` part doesn't work properly anymore, since there is no `ds.TemperatureRange` column

Answer (score 0):

Ah, got it!

The problem I was having was because in the ON statement I was trying to group on `TemperatureRange = ds2.TemperatureRange`, where TemperatureRange came from the first query.

Instead if I replace it with `ds.HighTemperature - ds.LowTemperature = ds2.TemperatureRange` all is well!